# php function in a while Loop

Tags: php, function, while-loop

i searched all over the web or i just don't see it.

I want to do the following:

```
<?php

 function abc(){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
   $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

?>

<? while(abc()) : ?>

   <?=article_title()?>
   <?=article_content()?>

<?=endwhile;?>
```

Could somebody give me a direction and/or example?

Thank you very much

Comment: wat do u want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: mysql_free_result() on the result when you are done.

Comment: something like wordpress they use, while(function()):, endwhile;. i want to make something similar, it makes a template designing much easier

Comment: do you want to print the results of the function ? do whiel loops r quite simple to use, but I still dont know what exactly u want to achieve, apart from using a do while loop ! Which u find all over the web ! So give us a bit more detail on why u want this loop, what u want to achieve !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to do something like that?

```
<?php
function getData(){
    //get the data from the database
    //return an array where each component is an element found
}

$elems = getData();
foreach($elems as $e){
    doSomethingWith($e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not have generator/iterator functions, so you cannot do that.

You can however return an array and iterate over that array:

```
function abc() {
    // ...
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $rows[] = $row; }
    return $rows;
}

foreach(abc() as $row) {
    // do something
}
```

If the functions you call need access to the row, pass it as an argument. Using global variables for it would be **very bad/nasty**

Comment: That's why I said iterator *functions*. In python you could do what the OP wanted using the `yield` keyword - which does not exist in PHP.